# Cannot build proper JSON with data coming from controller class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

Here is my code for Model Class:

```
public class GridModel
{
    public double ID { get; set; }
    public string SHORT_NAME { get; set; }
    public string CARRIER_NAME { get; set; }
    public List<GridSparklineModel> SellDuration { get; set; }
}

public class GridSparklineModel
{
    public DateTime YMDH { get; set; }
    public double SELL_DURATION { get; set; }
    public string DateString { get { return YMDH.ToString("h tt"); } }
}
```

------------------ controller ---------------------

public class GridController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Grid/

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public class JsonNetActionResult : ActionResult
    {
        public Object Data { get; private set; }

        public JsonNetActionResult(Object data)
        {
            this.Data = data;
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.HttpContext.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data));
        }
    }

    public JsonNetActionResult FetchGraphDataJSON()
    {
        List<GridModel> data = new List<GridModel>();

        //DataFetching Logic
        DataTable dt = FetchFirstDataTable();

        if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                GridModel model = new GridModel();

                model.ID = Convert.ToDouble(row["ID"].ToString());
                model.SHORT_NAME = row["SHORT_NAME"].ToString();
                model.CARRIER_NAME = row["CARRIER_NAME"].ToString();

                model.SellDuration = new List<GridSparklineModel>();

                double carrierId = Convert.ToDouble(row["ID"].ToString());

                DataTable dt2 = GetDt2();

                foreach (DataRow item2 in dt2.Select("ID=" + carrierId))
                {
                    model.SellDuration.Add(new GridSparklineModel { YMDH = DateTime.Parse(item2["YMDH"].ToString()), SELL_DURATION = Convert.ToDouble(item2["SELL_DURATION"]) });
                }

                data.Add(model);
            }
        }

        return new JsonNetActionResult(data);
    }

    public DataTable FetchFirstDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(double));
        dt.Columns.Add("SHORT_NAME");
        dt.Columns.Add("CARRIER_NAME");

        dt.Rows.Add(1, "A", "Carrier A");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "B", "Carrier B");
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "C", "Carrier C");
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "D", "Carrier D");
        dt.Rows.Add(5, "E", "Carrier E");
        dt.Rows.Add(6, "F", "Carrier F");
        dt.Rows.Add(7, "G", "Carrier G");
        return dt;
    }

    public DataTable GetDt2()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("YMDH");
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(double));
        dt.Columns.Add("SELL_DURATION");

        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 00:00:00.000", 1, 222.999995);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 01:00:00.000", 1, 75.816664);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 02:00:00.000", 1, 39.349995);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 03:00:00.000", 1, 275.91666);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 04:00:00.000", 1, 352.666641);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 00:00:00.000", 2, 80.783324);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 01:00:00.000", 2, 162.049985);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 02:00:00.000", 2, 107.199989);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 03:00:00.000", 2, 44.849994);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 04:00:00.000", 2, 156.516658);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 05:00:00.000", 2, 467.583312);
        dt.Rows.Add("2009-03-07 06:00:00.000", 2, 455.199977);

        return dt;
    }
}
```

------------------cshtml-----------------------

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("FetchGraphDataJSON", "Grid")';

        var rawData = null;
        $.ajax({
            // have to use synchronous here, else the function
            // will return before the data is fetched
            async: false,
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                rawData = data;
            }
        });

        var plotData = []

         for (i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {     
         // This has to be modified such that it builds the JSON like this [{"ID":1,"SHORT_NAME":"A","CARRIER_NAME":"Carrier A","SellDuration":[{"YMDH":"2009-03-07 00:00:00.000","SELL_DURATION":222.999995},{"YMDH":"2009-03-07 05:00:00.000","SELL_DURATION":275.91666}]}];           
            plotData.push([rawData[i].ID, rawData[i].SHORT_NAME, rawData[i].CARRIER_NAME], [rawData[i].SellDuration]);
        }

});

</script>
```

Can anybody please suggest how do I write the above statement so that it build JSON like this:
 var plotData = [{ "ID": 1, "SHORT_NAME": "A", "CARRIER_NAME": "Carrier A", "SellDuration": [{ "YMDH": "2009-03-07 00:00:00.000", "SELL_DURATION": 222.999995 }, { "YMDH": "2009-03-07 01:00:00.000", "SELL_DURATION": 75.816664 }, { "YMDH": "2009-03-07 02:00:00.000", "SELL_DURATION": 39.349995 }, { "YMDH": "2009-03-07 03:00:00.000", "SELL_DURATION": 75.816664 }, { "YMDH": "2009-03-07 04:00:00.000", "SELL_DURATION": 39.349995 }, { "YMDH": "2009-03-07 05:00:00.000", "SELL_DURATION": 275.91666 }] },
            { "ID": 1, "SHORT_NAME": "B", "CARRIER_NAME": "Carrier A", "SellDuration": [{ "YMDH": "2009-03-07 00:00:00.000", "SELL_DURATION": 222.999995 }, { "YMDH": "2009-03-07 01:00:00.000", "SELL_DURATION": 75.816664 }, { "YMDH": "2009-03-07 02:00:00.000", "SELL_DURATION": 39.349995 }, { "YMDH": "2009-03-07 03:00:00.000", "SELL_DURATION": 75.816664 }, { "YMDH": "2009-03-07 04:00:00.000", "SELL_DURATION": 39.349995 }, { "YMDH": "2009-03-07 05:00:00.000", "SELL_DURATION": 275.91666 }] }
        ];

Please advise.

Comment: this is a bit complex, this there some simple way to show JSON as required.

Comment: Sorry, I sent wrong comment before, as I see you receiving Json and trying to modify it? Something like this: `plotData.push({ ID: rawData[i].ID, SHORT_NAME: rawData[i].SHORT_NAME, CARRIER_NAME: rawData[i].CARRIER_NAME, SellDuration: rawData[i].SellDuration });` ?

Comment: No this does not build the JSON as desired :(                           Since the SellDuration would be having multiple values so do you think we need to loop through that separately.

Comment: yes, you should create another array, fill it with data in loop and then assign to SellDuration, but I think it's better to change server code for returning data as desired, if it's possible.